# Using Firebase with Webpack and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, webpack

I'm trying to pull some data from a Firebase instance, but am running into an issue when trying to bind it to a variable. I'm using TypeScript and Webpack to build.

**main.ts**

```
import * as Firebase from 'firebase';

class filter {
    constructor(){
        let ref = new Firebase('my-url-here');
    }
}
```

The typings and npm module are installed and working, and Visual Code brings up no errors, but when I hit the browser I get:

**ERROR**

```
TypeError: Firebase is not a constructor
```

..

Logging Firebase to the console returns an object with methods like `auth`, `app` and `database`, but none of these seem to work either (or I'm calling them incorrectly). Any ideas?

A general best practice on how to incorporate Firebase into a Webpack/TypeScript would be just as welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project i had the same error: It was caused by the `firebase.json` file which i guess got picked up by webpack.

As i can only guess why it happened: Webpack creating a symbol "Firebase" which replaced the constructor of firebase itself.

Have you done a `firebase init` in your directory?

Also see : https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/187

Comment: The `init` was the cause thanks :) Once I initialised the app with a config it worked as expected. Thanks!